# finding an adjacent node in xml through xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

i have a deeply nested structure (actually parsing out xhtml, so lots of nasty), like so:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <font id="blah">
      stuff
    </font>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
      more stuff
  </td>
</tr>
```

and this repeats in a long table. i need an xpath expression that will select the second font tag (or rather it's `text()`). i was looking at the `preceding-sibling` axis, but something isn't quite working right.

something along the lines of (and pardon me if this is ridiculous, my xpath is rusty)

```
//tr[preceding-sibling::tr/td/font]/td/text()
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted text node. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use**:

```
(//tr/td[font])[2]/font/text()
```

**This means**:

Select all text-node children of all `font` elements that are children of the second `td` in the document that has a `font` child and is itself a child of some `tr` element.

**As you can see, no `preceeding` axis is necessary**.

Comment: oh, that works too. i figured out what was wrong with mine - it was working, but grabbing *all* rows that followed that first tr. i changed it to be //tr[preceding-sibling::tr[1]/td/font]/td/text(), and that worked too. basically needed to specify that i wanted the preceding sibling to the the first row. yours is a lot simpler though.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea. It should work if you get rid of the `/b` in there.

Comment: yeah - the /b is a copy/paste mistake. it's needed in the actual expression, but not in my example here.